# How to increase delta value of a multiple valued field +1?

Tags: views

I would like to output the delta value of a multiple image field as a affix for the image title in a view, but increased with 1. So, it should start with 1 not with 0. How can I do this?

Why do I need this? I need to reference to the images from articles using the scheme *Fig. 1*, *Fig. 2* etc. There for the view output should look like:

```
+----------------+
|                |
|    an image    |
|    delta 0     |
|                |
+----------------+
Fig. 1: Image Title

+----------------+
|                |
|    an image    |
|    delta 1     |
|                |
+----------------+
Fig. 2: Image Title

+----------------+
|                |
|    an image    |
|    delta 2     |
|                |
+----------------+
Fig. 3: Image Title
```

The first thing I tried is, to sort the view by delta and than output "Global: View result counter", but this does not work if a filter is applied to the view. If a filter is in action, the numeration would not be concordant with the delta anymore.

Do I have to write an custom formatter? And when, where do I start, I don't have an idea.

Comment: Are you not seeing the delta as a field that you can add to the view?  Did you try using that and rewriting the output?

Comment: @MPD I know about the field, but how to rewrite the output? I want to avoid the `php filter` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what you're planning to do with that delta. Here's a possible solution for you:

Use Aggregation on the view and use "max" for the delta.  Hide the field and then do a math operation to add +1 to the value of the delta.

If you could expound on the "why" it would help.

Comment: I updated my question. To use aggregation is a smart idea, but I think it would not work for my purpose (s. above).

Comment: Ah!  I see.  My answer still stands.  Just don't aggregate.  Use the global math calculation and assuming you've added the delta to the field and hidden it:  [delta] + 1. Caveat.  Filters will mess with the numbering here too cause delta represents its position in the array of images rather than the view.

Comment: You are my hero! Did not know about this field!

Comment: Thanks, Rob. This did what I needed without aggregration - I simply did what was suggested in Rob's subsequent comment. The "Why" for me was to output the delta+1 as a counter on a list of items. Numbering them from 0 wasn't an option.